# How to block dialog boxes in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, popups, productivity

For the following 2 reasons I am trying to block the dialog box pop-ups that the chrome browser itself occasionally presents:

1. As a workaround for the in-ability to block uninstallation of chrome extensions.
2. To block the grey boxes with questions because I find them annoying. (I accept the inabilities that follow from not having that interaction option with the browser.)

This is the type of popup that I am trying to block:

[image: Example of such a grey box.]

So far I explored all the conventional settings in the chrome browser. As far as I am aware they do not contain an option to block those dialog boxes.

An option would not be to write a script that continously presses the `Esc` key if the chrome browser is being used because that  is a keyboard shortcut for the Stop button, so pressing it continuously would make the browser unusable as was mentioned in the answer. But perhaps a creative mind has a less intrusive option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Those are dialog boxes. They are a standard part of interaction with the web browser, and cannot be disabled.

If you want to prevent an extension from being uninstalled, you can accomplish this with [the `ExtensionInstallForcelist` policy setting](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

As an aside, the Esc key is a keyboard shortcut for the Stop button, so pressing it continuously would make the browser unusable.

Comment: thank you! Just to be clear for those trying to do the same thing: that option is designed for the Open Source equivalent to the Chrome web browser; Chromium. And the process off applying that solution is documented and led to a new question about its implementation here: https://superuser.com/questions/1328465/prevent-un-installation-of-the-stayfocusd-extension-in-chromium-using-extension .

Comment: Read the first paragraph of the page I linked to. It addresses your question.